# How to move forms, classes or other code files to a subfolder?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a .NET project in VS 2010 that has grown to consist of a large number of forms, classes and other code files. I am liking the idea of grouping some of these files into subfolders, but when I attempt to move them, a namespace nightmare begins.

Upon moving a form to a subfolder, Resharper complains that the namespace does not correspond to file location, and suggests a namespace change from "MyNamespace" to "MyNamespace.Subfolder"

If I do this, of course all references to the form then also need to be updated.

Should I ignore the namespace suggestion, or is there some better way to organize code files after-the-fact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Resharper (which you appear to be), it has a feature for sorting this out for you.

You should move the file, and then right-click the project and select [Refactor]->[Adjust Namespaces] - it should then fix all the namespaces in that project for you.

This allows you to move multiple files and then fix the namespaces for them all in one go (or at least per project)

Comment: @JYelton Yeah, i just changed the filenames and namespaces for every file in a fairly large project and this saved me LOADS of time.

Comment: Yes, with Resharper this is a breeze: right-click the misplaced/outlier page, and then select Refactor | Move. Select the subfolder to which you want to move it, select "Next" and voila!